# Add a string after before slash

Tags: php, url

If I have the following URL as a string:

```
www.example.com/img/1.png
```

How would I add the string `extra/` after the last slash in the URL, so its result is:

```
www.example.com/img/extra/1.png
```

Comment: Add the tag .htaccess. I think that is the tool you need for this problem. It'll lead people who can solve it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
echo preg_replace('#(/[^/]+)(?=/[^/]+/?$)#', '$1/extra', $url);
```

**Explanation:**

```bash
(        # group and capture to backreference $1
  /      # match literal '/'
  [^/]+  # any character except: '/' (1 or more times)
)        # end of capturing group 1
(?=      # look ahead to see if there is:  '/'
  [^/]+  # any character except: '/' (1 or more times)
  /?     # '/' (optional)
  $      # assert position at the end of string
)        # end of look-ahead
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation.